# javascript trigger hovering on absolute element and element under absolute element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to detect hover event on both: absolute positioned element and element lying under it.

Here's simplified problem:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
<div id="output"></div>    
<div id="output2"></div>
<svg width="40" height="40" id="svg">
    <circle r="20" cx="20" cy="20"></circle>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    background-color: green;    
}
#svg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 15px;
}
```

JS:

```
var output = $("#output");
$("#content").mouseenter(function(e){
    output.text("in text");
}).mouseout(function(e) {
    output.text("out text"); 
});

var output2 = $("#output2");
$("#svg").mouseenter(function(e){
    output2.text("in svg");
}).mouseleave(function(e) {
    output2.text("out svg"); 
});
```

And jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r4xgq9s8/1/.

EDIT:

I want to have following results:

- (in text, in svg) when you are over both,
- (out text, in svg) when you are only over #svg, not #content,
- (in text, out svg) when you are only over #content, not #svg,
- (out text, out svg) when you aren't over them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work because the circle hides the content below it.
However there are possibilities you can check out:

- Make the circle child of the content. This way the hover-event bubbles up. This way all the content of the circle will output both "over text" and "over svg" which is not really what you wanted
- Write a bit math and check if you are over the text

I will try one approach for the second one here:

```js
var output = $("#output");
var inCircle = false;

$("#content").mouseenter(function(e) {
  output.text("in text");
}).mouseout(function(e) {
  output.text("out text");
});

var output2 = $("#output2");
$("#svg").mouseenter(function(e) {
  output2.text("in svg");
  inCircle = true;
}).mouseleave(function(e) {
  output2.text("out svg");
  inCircle = false;
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {

  if (!inCircle) return; // When not in circle we return here

  var $content = $('#content');
  var offset = $content.offset();

  // Check if in content-element
  if (e.pageX > offset.left &&
    e.pageX < offset.left + $content.width() &&
    e.pageY > offset.top &&
    e.pageY < offset.top + $content.height()) {

    $content.trigger('mouseenter');
  } else {
    $content.trigger('mouseout');
  }


});
```

```css
#content {
  background-color: green;
}
#svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="output2"></div>
<svg width="40" height="40" id="svg">
  <circle r="20" cx="20" cy="20"></circle>
</svg>
```

The trick here is that we listen to the document-mousemove. Whenever we are in the circle and the mouse moves over the content we trigger the mouseenter on the content. Vice versa with mouseleave.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't resolve my problem: in target page I want to have many #content like elements, so I couldn't make #svg to be their child.

Also math is not a good idea if #content would be some polygon...

Comment: In which html-case a div would ever be a polygon? And there is no problem to adapt that example to many divs. There is no other solution for your problem because thats how html works. However this answer is correct and a valid answer to your question

Comment: I don't say div would be a polygon, but some element with this id.
Ok, I'll close this question if you think that there are no more ways to resolve it.

Comment: I dont think that there is any possibility then

Answer (score 0):

I added this new answer to solve the point-in-polygon-Problem mentioned in the comments from my first answer.

To check if a [point is in a polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) you have to implement an algorithm which is designed to solve this non-trivial problem.
I will show one of these implementions here.

```
function point_in_polygon(P,R){

    function det(i){
        return (P[i].x - R.x) * (P[i+1].y - R.y) - (P[i+1].x - R.x) * (P[i].y - R.y);
    }

    var w = 0,
        len = p.length,
        i = 0,
        q = [];

    for(;i < len;++i){

        if(P[i].x > R.x && P[i].y >= R.y) q[i] = 0;
        if(P[i].x <= R.x && P[i].y > R.y) q[i] = 1;
        if(P[i].x < R.x && P[i].y <= R.y) q[i] = 2;
        if(P[i].x >= R.x && P[i].y < R.y) q[i] = 3;

    }

    q[len] = q[0];

    for(i = 0;i < len;++i){

        switch(q[i+1] - q[i]){
            case -3: ++w; break;
            case  3: --w; break;
            case -2: if(det(i) > 0) ++w; break;
            case  2: if(det(i) < 0) --w; break;
        }

    }

    return w;
}
```

This function expects 2 Parameter. The first contains all Points of the Polygon with the startPoint and endPoint the same:

```
var P = [
    {x:50, y:50},
    {x:200, y:30},
    {x:150, y:100},
    {x:300, y:300},
    {x:100, y:200},
    {x:50, y:50},
];
```

The second one is the current Point which needs to be checked:

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){

    var R = {x:e.pageX, y:e.pageY};

}
```

The `point_in_polygon`-function returns the `winding-number` which is greater zero when the point is inside the polygon.

This function can easily adapted to all situations when not using a box but a polygon.